# Running from Command Line Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line

I am unable to execute a JAR file from the command line. It is returning a ClassNotFoundException and is referencing the database driver class. The application runs fine within Netbeans.

```
C:\temp> java -classpath C:\Temp\db2jcc.jar;C:\Temp\CatalystIncomingWire.jar -jar .\CatalystIncomingWire.jar file.txt

C:\temp> java -classpath .\db2jcc.jar -jar .\CatalystIncomingWire.jar file.txt

java -jar .\CatalystIncomingWire.jar file.txt
```

Code that loads the driver

```
        //Create DB2 connection
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");        
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2://keystone:50000/"+db,"user","pass");
```

It will read a file and output a new one. Works fine within netbeans.

Comment: According to the documentation you have to include `db2jcc4.jar` in your classpath as well.

Comment: I thought that's what i was doing? At least in the first two examples. Is that not the correct way to include a classpath?

Comment: There are ***two*** jar files, `db2jcc.jar` and `db2jcc4.jar`.

Comment: java -classpath .\db2jcc.jar .\db2jcc4.jar -jar .\CatalystIncomingWire.jar .\324172575IncomingDomestic04182019.txt
Error: Could not find or load main class .\db2jcc4.jar

Comment: When I add a semicolon between the two jar files it doesn't accept it, I just get the helplist

Comment: You cannot use `-classpath` and `-jar` on the same command line.  Please refer to the manual entry for the `java` command.  (And the dup Q&A)